# Django - Handling multiple form requests in a template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I may not have worded the question the best but what I would like to know is what would be a good/best way for handling multiple request possibilities from a template?

For ex. I have a template that displays a form along with any attachments that are held in a separate table but directly relate to the current record. So I have a submit button for the form and I also have 2 other buttons that are for adding and deleting the attachments from the separate table.

I have handled the adding of the attachment by utilizing the `name` attribute on the `input` tag. I initially thought of doing the same thing with deleting but I did not have a way of passing the `ID` of the record to the view function so I created a separate URL to process that request. The issue with this approach is that I can no longer pass the same form instance back to the user. Once the user hits delete it resets the form basically.

Is it typical/preferred to create some URLs solely for processing requests?
I have a feeling that the best answer would be to use AJAX requests but I am trying to get the functionality working before I make changes for performance reasons.

I have included the entire functions below but I am just concerned about the way the requests are being handled and if I should be doing things differently.

## Views.py

```
def create_req(request):
    all_attachments = TempAttachments.objects.filter(username=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        req_form = ReqForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if request.POST.get("Add") and len(request.FILES) != 0:
            add_attachment = TempAttachments.objects.create(attachment=request.FILES['attachment'], username=request.user)

        elif req_form.is_valid():
            cur_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=request.user)
            basket_item = ReqBasket.objects.create(user=cur_user,
                                description = req_form.cleaned_data['description'].capitalize(),
                                extra_information = req_form.cleaned_data['extra_information'],
                                quantity = req_form.cleaned_data['quantity'],
                                price = req_form.cleaned_data['price'],
                                total_price = req_form.cleaned_data['quantity']*req_form.cleaned_data['price'],
                                assistance = req_form.cleaned_data['assistance'],
                                catagory = req_form.cleaned_data['catagory'])

            return redirect(reverse('requisition:basket'))
        else:
            req_form = ReqForm(request.POST)
    else:
        req_form = ReqForm()

    return render(request, 'req/create_req.html', {'req_form': req_form, 'all_attachments': all_attachments})

def remove_temp_attachment(request, id):
    attachment = get_object_or_404(TempAttachments, id=id, username=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        req_form = ReqForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        attachment.delete()
        return redirect(reverse('requisition:create_req'), {'req_form':req_form})
    else:
        return redirect(reverse('requisition:create_req'))
```

## Template.py - Sorry can't get the bootstrap to work

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
{% extends 'registration/home.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<h1>New Requisition</h1>
    
<form method="post" action="{% url 'requisition:create_req' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {% for field in req_form.visible_fields %}
        {% ifnotequal field.label 'Notes' %}
        {% if field.label == 'Attachment' %}
        <tr> 
            <th>{{ field.label_tag }}</th>
            <td>
                {{ field }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Add" name="Add">
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% else %}    
        <tr> 
            <th>{{ field.label_tag }}</th>
            <td>
                {{ field }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}
        {% endifnotequal %}
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Add To Basket">
</form>

<a href="{% url 'requisition:basket' %}">Back</a>

<table class='table'>
    {% if all_attachments %}
    {% for attachment in all_attachments %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{% get_media_prefix %}/{{attachment.attachment}}">{{attachment}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action="{% url 'requisition:remove_temp_attachment' attachment.id %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" value="Delete">
            </form>      
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</table>


{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: What is the reason for not combining these forms into one?

Comment: That kind of ties with my question. The second form is calling a different function from the view that would require information from the database that is not available through just the initial function. I'm trying to understand if this is bad practice or if it is normal to have some URL's solely as processing functions. I feel like this would get cumbersome but I'm still learning Django so I'm not really sure.

Comment: http://www.joshuakehn.com/2013/7/18/multiple-django-forms-in-one-form.html